# MySQL workbench shows error when creating foreign keys

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to add to foreign keys into my table using MySQL Workbench and when I apply the software executes the code below:

```
ALTER TABLE `insect_db`.`usu_ins` 
ADD INDEX `fk_id_ins_idx` (`id_ins` ASC) VISIBLE,
ADD INDEX `fk_id_cad_idx` (`id_cad` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
ALTER TABLE `insect_db`.`usu_ins` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_id_ins`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_ins`)
  REFERENCES `insect_db`.`insects` (`entry_cod`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_id_cad`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_cad`)
  REFERENCES `insect_db`.`cadastro` (`entry_cod`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `insect_db`.`usu_ins` 
ADD INDEX `fk_id_ins_idx` (`id_ins` ASC) VISIBLE,
ADD INDEX `fk_id_cad_idx` (`id_cad` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
ALTER TABLE `insect_db`.`usu_ins` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_id_ins`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_ins`)
  REFERENCES `insect_db`.`insects` (`entry_cod`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_id_cad`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_cad`)
  REFERENCES `insect_db`.`cadastro` (`entry_cod`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
ADD INDEX `fk_id_cad_idx` (`id_cad` ASC) VISIBLE' at line 2
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `insect_db`.`usu_ins` 
ADD INDEX `fk_id_ins_idx` (`id_ins` ASC) VISIBLE,
ADD INDEX `fk_id_cad_idx` (`id_cad` ASC) VISIBLE
```

I've tried to search for a solution but nothing has worked so far. What should i do?

Comment: Try to separate the two ADD INDEX into two ALTER TABLE commands. Most Mysql alter table DDL allows only to change one thing at a time.

Comment: AHH the old mysql workbench insisting on adding VISIBLE when your version of mysql doesn't yet support it...

Comment: You are right, just removing the VISIBLE's was enough for running the code! Thanks!